# How to draw a rectangle around the contours?

Tags: opencv, contour, edge-detection

I am just starting out with opencv and I am trying to make a program that puts squares around a picture of rocks on some sand. The documentation for the function [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) includes an example of how to use it.

```
findContours( src, contours, hierarchy,
  CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

The prototype of findContours is

```
void findContours(InputOutputArray image, OutputArrayOfArrays contours, OutputArray hierarchy, int mode, int method, Point offset=Point()) ;
```

I have two questions. 
1. The third argument in the example `hierarchy` is a `vector<Vec4i>` does not match the type findContours expects. Why is that? 
2. How does one use the data stored in `contours` to find where the contours are to create a bounding box?

Comment: "The prototype of findContours is"
and then comes : void drawContours(..)  did you mean that ? pasted the wrong signature ?

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the wrong signature all along, that makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours( mask, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);
for ( size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i )
{
    cv::drawContours( img, contours, i, Scalar(200,0,0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() ); 
    cv::Rect brect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    cv::rectangle(img, brect, Scalar(255,0,0));
}
```