# Calculate the bounding box from a body extraction mask

Tags: c++, opencv, bounding-box

I ve got a binary mat file, which contain only black and white pixel. Basically is a body extraction mask and I want to calculate the bounding box. How can I calculate the min and max white value from that binary image in order to calculate the bouding box of the shapped calculated? My code:

```
Mat bodyEx(string filename){

cv::Mat matInput=cv::imread(filename);

//Set mask
cv::Mat matMask = cv::Mat::ones(matInput.size(), CV_8U) * cv::GC_BGD;
cv::Rect area;
area.x=int(matInput.cols*0.1);  area.y=int(matInput.rows*0.05);
area.width=int(matInput.cols-2*area.x);
area.height=int(matInput.rows-2*area.y);
rectangle(matMask, area , cv::Scalar(cv::GC_PR_FGD),-1,8,0);
area.x=int(matInput.cols*0.35); area.y=int(matInput.rows*0.25);
area.width=matInput.cols-2*area.x;
area.height=matInput.rows-2*area.y;
rectangle(matMask, area , cv::Scalar(cv::GC_FGD),-1,8,0);

//Segmentation
cv::Mat bgd,fgd;
cv::grabCut(matInput, matMask, area, bgd, fgd, 1, cv::GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);
matMask= matMask&1;
cv::compare(matMask,cv::GC_FGD,matMask,cv::CMP_EQ);
cv::Mat matSegmented=cv::Mat::zeros(matInput.size(),CV_8UC3);
matInput.copyTo(matSegmented,matMask);


int lowestWhite_x;  int lowestWhite_y;
cout << "Rows " << matMask.rows << " and cols: "<< matMask.cols << endl;
for (int row=0;row<matMask.rows;row++) 
    { 
       for (int col=0;col<matMask.cols;col++) 
        {
            if(matMask.at<uchar>(row,col) != 0){lowestWhite_x = row; lowestWhite_y = col;}
        } 
    }

cout << "Rows " << lowestWhite_x << " and cols: "<< lowestWhite_y << endl;
//Display
/*cv::imshow("InputImage",matInput);
cv::imshow("mask",matMask);
cv::imshow("Segmented",matSegmented);
cvWaitKey();*/

return matSegmented;
```

}

EDIT:

```
Rect faceRect, brect;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours( matMask, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);
for ( size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i )
{
    cv::drawContours( matInput, contours, i, Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() ); 
    cv::Rect brect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    cv::rectangle(matInput, brect, Scalar(0,255,0));
    cout << brect.size() << endl;
}
```

It calculates all the contours. Finally I want to keep the bb. 4 points not all the contours of the image. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the contours on the binary image using [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#cv.FindContours) function and find the bounding rectangle using [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) function.

An example of the usage can be found here: [How to draw a rectangle around the contours?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15590600/773226)

Response to your edit:
Try `Rect myRect =  boundingRect(contours[i]);` instead of `Rect myRect =  boundingRect(contours);` is wrong.

Comment: What exactly I calculate using findContours?

Comment: In your masked image, the person will be white and background black. Consider there are two objects in white color, both separated. Using the function, it distinguishes different non connected objects and outputs the bounding points of all objects. Thus you get the bounding point of a person in image. boundingRect draws a rectangle connecting these bounding points.

Comment: vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(matMask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
Rect myRect =  boundingRect(contours);

Comment: Rect myRect =  boundingRect(contours[i]);

Comment: Resonse to second edit: In your case, if my understanding is correct, two contours will be found. You will only need the contour of the smallest rectangle (the one that is not representing the whole of the image). You could easily the math to find it!

Comment: Ok I ve got it, finally i ve to find the contour with highest width and height.